# How to move an object according to the top left hand corner of another one in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates

I have two objects : a quad A and a cube B. A is scaled : `scale_A = Vector3(10, 10, 1)`. B has to be placed according to the top left hand corner of A. Because B must not inherit scale from A, B is NOT a child - so **we DON'T have** `B.transform.SetParent(A, false)` nor `B.transform.SetParent(A)`.

So, I would want to place B according to the top left hand corner of A, **taking account A's scaling.**

For example :

1. B, at position `(0, 0, 1)`, should be precisely at the top left hand corner of A.
2. B, at position `(width_of_A_taking_account_A's_scale, height_of_A_taking_account_A's_scale, 1)`, should be precisely at the bottom right hand corner of A.

I spent a lot of time trying to use `SetParent`, but it requires to re-scale B according to A's scaling and in my project that's simply not possible. So I wish to avoid to make B child of A.

Comment: What kind of object is A? Is it a 3d object. Also, is it rectangular shaped?

Comment: A is a quad, B is a cube. Are you going to give me some tip with coordinates computing or something like this ? ^^ I would prefer to call a Unity function rather than computing myself some values

Comment: I don't know any other ways to get the corner position by calling some default function in Unity. Anyways, I posted my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Quad as object A, you can make use of the `MeshFilter` vertex.
First get the top left vertex and then transform the point according to A `GameObject`. Then place the B `GameObject` in that transformed position. Here's the script that worked for me.

```c#
public class PosBOnA : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject A;
    public GameObject B;

    MeshFilter meshA;
    Vector3 leftTopCornerA;

    void Awake()
    {
        meshA = A.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        leftTopCornerA = A.transform.TransformPoint(meshA.sharedMesh.vertices[3]);
        B.transform.position = leftTopCornerA;            
    }
}
```